# UTF8-aware printf?

Tags: utf-8, printf, ocaml, ocaml-core

AFAIK, strings in OCaml are just plain sequences of bytes. They have no notion of encoding.

This is fine for most purposes. However, some pieces of standard library make assumptions about the string being encoded in a single-byte charset, for example the aligning features of `printf`:

```
# printf "[%4s]\n[%4s]\n" "a" "à";;
[   a]
[  à]
- : unit = ()
```

Is there an upgraded `printf` somewhere that deals with this correctly, for example by looking at LANG and LC_* to guess the encoding being used on the terminal? (I'm using Core)

Answer (score 5):

If you need to print UTF-8 data you can use `Uuseg`'s [pretty printers](http://erratique.ch/software/uuseg/doc/Uuseg_string.html#pp).

Comment: I didn't know the `width` flag could be used with `%s`. But apparently it doesn't work with `%a`. So not directly. But by using `Uuseg_string.fold_utf_8` on grapheme clusters you could easily implement your own UTF-8 aware left pad formatter.